# .TS file to .mp3 using FFMPEG in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, ffmpeg

Hi I am using `ffmpeg` for windows phone which was found [here](https://github.com/pinger-inc/FFMPEG_WindowsPhone). With this I am trying to convert a `.ts` file to `.mp3` file but the command that I am using is not working for this type of conversion, I have also noted that it works for certain other format conversions such as `ts` to `wma`, `ts` to `ogg` e.t.c . The commands that I have tried are

```
 -i sourcewithfullpath.ts destinationwithfullpath.mp3

 -i sourcewithfullpath.ts 
 -f destinationwithfullpath.mp3

 -i sourcewithfullpath.ts
 -c:a libmp3lame destinationwithfullpath.mp3 

 -i sourcewithfullpath.ts
 -acodec mp3 destinationwithfullpath.mp3
```

most of these gave me an `AccessViolationException` while calling `ffmpeg.Run()`
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MP3 encoding is via an external library, which doesn't look to be included in your ffmpeg build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  Mulvya is right MP3 encoding is not included in this `FFMPEG` build but I figured out another way which does not satisfy the exact need still a good option

```
-i sourcewithfullpath.ts 
-f destinationwithfullpath.mp2
```

`FFMPEG` does support `mp2` format, the file was converted to `mp2` audio and renamed to `mp3`, it is playable in the windows phone. Please note that the compression ratio of the `mp2` format is not that good compared to `mp3` format which means that the output file resulted in a much greater size which was almost double.